# Using string lengths specified in element to check another element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am writing a stylesheet to create a report on which text strings in a file are longer than allowed. (As far as know this is not possible to do with a schema 1.0.)

For each Text I am checking that the length of the string contained in the Value element does not exceed what is specified in the Info element for that particular text.

However, I have found out that my maxLength variable cannot be used as a global variable. So even though I am able to get the info about the max lengths I am not able to use those values in my checks. 
I could use some advice on how to best re-design my stylesheet.

My XSL:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <!-- Message template -->
    <xsl:template match="Text" >
        <xsl:variable name="messageNumber" select="@Id"/>
        <xsl:variable name="maxLength"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="(normalize-space(Info)='')">
                <xsl:variable name="maxLength" select="40" />
                Message <xsl:value-of select="$messageNumber"/> is missing Max Length. Using <xsl:value-of select="$maxLength"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains(Info,'char')">
                <xsl:variable name="maxLength1" select="substring-before(Info, 'char')"/>
                <xsl:variable name="maxLength" select="substring($maxLength1,  string-length($maxLength1) - 2)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose> 

        <xsl:choose>    
            <xsl:when test="string-length(Value) &gt; $maxLength">
                Message <xsl:value-of select="$messageNumber"/> too long: <xsl:value-of select="string-length(Value)"/> chars (max is <xsl:value-of select="$maxLength"/>) 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                Message <xsl:value-of select="$messageNumber"/> is OK: <xsl:value-of select="string-length(Value)"/> chars (max is <xsl:value-of select="$maxLength"/>) 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Texts>
  <Text Id="1">
    <Value>OK</Value>
    <Info>Text length for button, max 6 chars</Info>
  </Text>
  <Text Id="2">
    <Value>Cancel</Value>
    <Info>Button, Maximum length 9 chars</Info>
  </Text>
  <Text Id="3">
    <Value>Continue</Value>
    <Info>This text cannot be longer than 14 characters. Use short form if required.</Info>
  </Text>
  <Text Id="4">
    <Value>Twinkle, twinkle little star</Value>
    <Info>Title text, Maximum length 14 chars.</Info>
  </Text>
  <Text Id="5">
    <Value>Twinkle, twinkle little star again</Value>
    <Info></Info>
  </Text>
</Texts>
```

The desired output is something like this:

```
Message 1 is OK: 2 chars (max is 6)
Message 2 is OK: 6 chars (max is 9)
Message 3 is OK: 8 chars (max is 14)
Message 4 too long: 28 chars (max is 14)
Message 5 is missing Max Length. Using 40
Message 5 is OK: 34 chars (max is 40)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in XSLT are immutable, and cannot be changed once set. What your XSLT is doing is initialising a new variable called `maxLength` within the `xsl:when` statements, which is local in scope to that block (It is said to "shadow" the main variable).

What you need to do have separate statements to initialise `maxLength` and to display the message.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <!-- Message template -->
    <xsl:template match="Text" >
        <xsl:variable name="messageNumber" select="@Id"/>

        <xsl:variable name="maxLength">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(normalize-space(Info)='')">40</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(Info,'char')">
                    <xsl:variable name="maxLength1" select="substring-before(Info, 'char')"/>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring($maxLength1,  string-length($maxLength1) - 2)" />
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose> 
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:if test="(normalize-space(Info)='')">
            Message <xsl:value-of select="$messageNumber"/> is missing Max Length. Using <xsl:value-of select="$maxLength"/>
        </xsl:if>

        <xsl:choose>    
            <xsl:when test="string-length(Value) &gt; $maxLength">
                Message <xsl:value-of select="$messageNumber"/> too long: <xsl:value-of select="string-length(Value)"/> chars (max is <xsl:value-of select="$maxLength"/>) 
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                Message <xsl:value-of select="$messageNumber"/> is OK: <xsl:value-of select="string-length(Value)"/> chars (max is <xsl:value-of select="$maxLength"/>) 
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```